# Material UI Card space between align of items of left column problem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Why are the items in the left column are not arranged in a "space-between" way? I want the dish name and the price to be at the top and bottom fixed positions.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw7xO.jpg]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Paper, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const DishCard = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <Paper sx={{ p: 1, bgcolor: '#F8EAD1', color: 'black' }}>
    <Grid container alignItems="center">
      <Grid  item xs={6} container direction="column" alignItems="flex-start" justifyContent='space-between' spacing={1}>
      
      <Grid container direction='row' alignItems='flex-start' justifyContent='space-between' p={1}>
            <Grid item xs={10}><Typography variant="body1" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
              {props.dish.name}
            </Typography></Grid>
            {props.dish.isGlutenFree &&<Grid item xs={1}><img src="/gluten-free2.png" alt="gluten free" width='100%' sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'inline-block' } }} /></Grid>}
            {props.dish.isVegetarian && <Grid item xs={1}><img src="/vegetarian.png" alt="vegetarian" width='100%' sx={{ display: { xs: 'block', sm: 'inline-block' } }} /></Grid>}
          
    </Grid> {/* end of row name, icons, items */}
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="body2" sx={{ pt: 1 }}>
            {props.dish.description.length > 45 ? props.dish.description.slice(0, 45) + "..." : props.dish.description}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="body2" sx={{ pt: 1 }}>
              {`$${props.dish.price}`}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <img src={props.dish.image} alt={props.dish.name} width="100%" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Paper>
  );
};

export default DishCard;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhEfw.png)
```

Im trying to position the items in the left column of the card in a space-between manner in fixed positions. I want the card to have fixed height.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw7xO.jpg